# Is it possible to a share a linux named pipe using samba?

Tags: linux, pipe, named-pipes, samba

I have a named pipe on my linux machine. On read, this file returns measurement values.
Now i want to make this pipe available to a remote machine as samba share (to fetch the data over the network). Therefore i added the containing folder to my samba shares.

When i mount the share on another linux machine, and try to "cat" the pipes content, i get a permission denied error. Using wireshark i saw, that the error came from the server (0xc0000022, STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED). However on the server, i can see in my debug logs, that the read access to the pipe happens. But the output doesn't come to the client.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=manuel,uid=1000,gid=1000,cache=none //192.168.1.116/measure ./remote
```

Does anyone has an idea or experience with named pipes shared with samba?

PS.
Reading "normal files" works as expected - no permission denied error etc.

PPS.
On Windows i can open the pipe, but it is empty.

Comment: The SMB protocol has explicit support for named pipes via the special `$IPC` share, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wpo/4de75e21-36fd-440a-859b-75accc74487c .